Can't further edit hosts file, after I already edited it?
I am trying to block access to certain websites on my computer. The first time I tried changing the hosts file I had no problem doing so. It worked the way I had intended it to the first time. The problem is that I went back and tried to edit the hosts file again to block more sites, and now it won't let me. It will claim that I am not an administrator, but I am. I tried running notepad as an administrator directly, which will create a new text file but it won't overwrite the original file. It will just create a new text file called hosts with the edited text in the same location, alongside the original (unchanged) hosts file. I tried changing the permissions on the hosts file to not be read only and it didn't help. (even though that didn't prevent me from editing it the first time) How do I fix this so I can block more websites?

Run Notepad as an administrator, then browse to and open hosts from within Notepad.

Please explain further what you mean when you say " I tried running notepad as an administrator directly, which will create a new text file but it won't overwrite the original file." That is not at all what "running notepad as an administrator" does. Please list exactly what you did and add that info to the question. Running Notepad as administrator will allow you to modify HOSTS, but the fact you see two hosts file side-by-side indicates to me that you're probably not removing the .txt extension when you save.

If you didn't know about it, there are free DNS services which let you block entire categories of websites, e.g., OpenDNS.

Easiest way to edit: 1. Open HOSTS file (does not need to be as admin). 2. Make changes. 3. Save HOSTS to Desktop, Documents, or other location. 4. Copy and paste file to correct location, which will give UAC prompt to do so.

For me, what works best is to copy the hosts file from its default location to any location you can edit, right-click, open with, Notepad. Make the changes there, hit CTRL-S to save and exit notepad. Now copy back the file to its default location. UAC will pop up and ask for permission. Grant it, and there you go, hosts file updated.

I tried saving it in another location (and changing the file type to not be 'txt' beforehand) with the intent of moving it to the etc folder. It won't save as anything other than a 'txt' file when I do this.

You are probably not removing the .txt extension, but, this also means that you're doing this process wrong, and not the way you did it the first time. You are probably not noticing this because you have Extensions hidden for known file types, which means that in Explorer you're seeing two "HOSTS" files, but one of them is actually "HOSTS.txt".
In Notepad, regardless whether you run it as Administrator or with normal permissions, when you create a NEW file and Save it, it will save the file as a .txt file. When you OPEN an existing file, of any type, and edit it, when you Save that file, it will save it as the type that file already is.
The HOSTS file does not have an extension.
So, the CORRECT way to do this is:

In File Explorer show extensions for all file types.
Delete the "HOSTS.txt" file.
Open Notepad as Administrator.
In the Open dialog navigate to the HOSTS file location and OPEN the EXISTING HOSTS file.
Edit the file and save it.
Confirm the changes are working.


I had already deleted the hosts text files. I did exactly this, but instead of saving automatically when I clicked the save button, it opened the box pick location and file type. I chose 'all files' for the selection in the 'save as type' box. It did the exact same thing as before because this was the exact process I was doing before. I already tried to make sure before that it wasn't selecting 'txt' as the file type.
